# What does it mean to "get the name part of the path"?

Tags: aem, definition, jackrabbit

In Adobe CQ, in the documentation for "Text.getName(path)" it says:

```
"Returns the name part of the path."
```

But what is the "name part" of a path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name part of the path is the name of the node. Mostly that would be the text that is present after the last `/`, in case there are no trailing slashes in the path.

For eg. The name would be `demo` for the path `/content/geometrixx/en/demo`

It is the same result which you get when you use `node.getName()`